# ReplicaSetId conflict while adding node MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset, database

When I try to add a new node to my replicate set I get this message:

> `{
>       "ok" : 0,
>       "errmsg" : "Our replica set ID of 5890ad86c92c6c88e8573df0 did not match that of 10.0.253.3:27017, which is 5890a6b137e1380d1e697f2a",
>       "code" : 103,
>       "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible"`
>   }

Comment: Hi Arthur; it's difficult to answer, because your question doesn't have much detail. Could you [edit] it to include more background, such as: 1 - the current configuration and state of the replica set; 2 - the current configuration and state of the node you are trying to add; 3 - the sequence of steps that led to the error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error and impossible to find out why ... I come back on the post to send the solution if others pass here.

#### Simply do not initialize the replicate on both servers:

I have two separate X and Y servers without mongodb, X and Y are IP addresses or domains.

1. Install mongodb on both servers
2. Edit the `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf` configuration files on both servers
3. [in file] Replace `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` with `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,X` on the X server
4. [in file] Replace `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` with `bindIp: 127.0.0.1,Y` on the Y server
5. [in file] Replace `#replication:` with `replication:` on both servers
6. [in file] Add `replSetName: "​​myReplicatName"` line under `replication:` on both servers
7. Launch mongo with the configuration file on both servers
8. **Only on server X** run `mongo` and type commands

Mongo commands:

```
rs.initiate ({
  _id: "rs0",
  members: [{
    _id: 1,
    host: "X:27017"
  }]
});
rs.add("Y:YPORT");
```