# replica set configuration incompatible

Tags: database, mongodb, replication, replicaset

I am trying to setup replica set but unsuccessful.

Here is the config file for all servers /etc/mongodb.conf:

```
security:
  keyFile: /opt/svn/mhealth-server-config/etc/mongokey

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

And here is the result of rs.status() command of the primary server

```
{
        "set" : "rs0",
        "date" : ISODate("2017-10-05T08:00:57.599Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(22),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1507190457, 90),
                        "t" : NumberLong(22)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1507190457, 121),
                        "t" : NumberLong(22)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1507190457, 90),
                        "t" : NumberLong(22)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "......",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 1256,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1507190457, 121),
                                "t" : NumberLong(22)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-10-05T08:00:57Z"),
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1507189204, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-10-05T07:40:04Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Next, I try to add a second server to the replica set, it printed with the following error message:

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set ID of 58fcaf004dd51cd984051968 did not match that of 13.76.170.50:27017, which is 59d3668ea39e555205ab2761",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible"
}
```

It is clearly that both servers having the same replica set name "rs0" so I do not know what causes the issue. I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962117/replicasetid-conflict-while-adding-node-mongodb) but it does not solve my problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Found one possilbe cause. I have started the secondary server with replSet=rs1. However I have change the config file appropriately, but it just didn't recognize the new replset rs0. I don't know now how to clear this setting from the secondary server

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue was that in the seconary server, it store 'rs1' replica set name in data path, so even if I put 'rs0' in the config file it won't recognize that and still start as 'rs1'

My solution, not the ideal one but it works. I removed completely data path from the secondary server, so it won't remember 'rs1', and then started it again.